# WAI-compliant TreeView with events won't work for expandable items

Tags: html, treeview, accessibility, wai-aria

I can trying to build a tree view or a control in tree structure which has an event associates with each tree item. I have found an example in https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-practices-1.1/examples/treeview/treeview-2/treeview-2b.html

[image]

However, in this example, the event can only be added in the non-expandable items, for example, Orange, Pineapple, etc.

If I want to have click event on expandable items, in this case, Fruits, what do I do?

My page needs to be fully WAI compliant.

Comment: This question would be improved by sharing what you've tried, or at least what your existing markup looks like.

Answer (score 1):

With a treeview the top level item should **never** be an item that leads somewhere or does anything other than opening sub items. If you need this behaviour it would then be a [flyout menu](https://www.w3.org/WAI/tutorials/menus/flyout/#use-button-as-toggle) or similar that you need.

However the solution is really simple if you do want a treeview, make the first item in the fruits sub-list "All Fruits".

### Example

Using the example you gave I added one extra item under the "Fruits" category that is "All Fruits" in the following snippet.

Notice how I increase `aria-setsize` and adjust `aria-posinset` to account for the new top level item.

```js
/*
*   This content is licensed according to the W3C Software License at
*   https://www.w3.org/Consortium/Legal/2015/copyright-software-and-document
*
*   File:   TreeitemLink.js
*
*   Desc:   Treeitem widget that implements ARIA Authoring Practices
*           for a tree being used as a file viewer
*/

/*
*   @constructor
*
*   @desc
*       Treeitem object for representing the state and user interactions for a
*       treeItem widget
*
*   @param node
*       An element with the role=tree attribute
*/

var TreeitemLink = function (node, treeObj, group) {

  // Check whether node is a DOM element
  if (typeof node !== 'object') {
    return;
  }

  node.tabIndex = -1;
  this.tree = treeObj;
  this.groupTreeitem = group;
  this.domNode = node;
  this.label = node.textContent.trim();
  this.stopDefaultClick = false;

  if (node.getAttribute('aria-label')) {
    this.label = node.getAttribute('aria-label').trim();
  }

  this.isExpandable = false;
  this.isVisible = false;
  this.inGroup = false;

  if (group) {
    this.inGroup = true;
  }

  var elem = node.firstElementChild;

  while (elem) {

    if (elem.tagName.toLowerCase() == 'ul') {
      elem.setAttribute('role', 'group');
      this.isExpandable = true;
      break;
    }

    elem = elem.nextElementSibling;
  }

  this.keyCode = Object.freeze({
    RETURN: 13,
    SPACE: 32,
    PAGEUP: 33,
    PAGEDOWN: 34,
    END: 35,
    HOME: 36,
    LEFT: 37,
    UP: 38,
    RIGHT: 39,
    DOWN: 40
  });
};

TreeitemLink.prototype.init = function () {
  this.domNode.tabIndex = -1;

  if (!this.domNode.getAttribute('role')) {
    this.domNode.setAttribute('role', 'treeitem');
  }

  this.domNode.addEventListener('keydown', this.handleKeydown.bind(this));
  this.domNode.addEventListener('click', this.handleClick.bind(this));
  this.domNode.addEventListener('focus', this.handleFocus.bind(this));
  this.domNode.addEventListener('blur', this.handleBlur.bind(this));

  if (this.isExpandable) {
    this.domNode.firstElementChild.addEventListener('mouseover', this.handleMouseOver.bind(this));
    this.domNode.firstElementChild.addEventListener('mouseout', this.handleMouseOut.bind(this));
  }
  else {
    this.domNode.addEventListener('mouseover', this.handleMouseOver.bind(this));
    this.domNode.addEventListener('mouseout', this.handleMouseOut.bind(this));
  }
};

TreeitemLink.prototype.isExpanded = function () {

  if (this.isExpandable) {
    return this.domNode.getAttribute('aria-expanded') === 'true';
  }

  return false;

};

/* EVENT HANDLERS */

TreeitemLink.prototype.handleKeydown = function (event) {
  var tgt = event.currentTarget,
    flag = false,
    char = event.key,
    clickEvent;

  function isPrintableCharacter (str) {
    return str.length === 1 && str.match(/\S/);
  }

  function printableCharacter (item) {
    if (char == '*') {
      item.tree.expandAllSiblingItems(item);
      flag = true;
    }
    else {
      if (isPrintableCharacter(char)) {
        item.tree.setFocusByFirstCharacter(item, char);
        flag = true;
      }
    }
  }

  this.stopDefaultClick = false;

  if (event.altKey || event.ctrlKey || event.metaKey) {
    return;
  }

  if (event.shift) {
    if (event.keyCode == this.keyCode.SPACE || event.keyCode == this.keyCode.RETURN) {
      event.stopPropagation();
      this.stopDefaultClick = true;
    }
    else {
      if (isPrintableCharacter(char)) {
        printableCharacter(this);
      }
    }
  }
  else {
    switch (event.keyCode) {
      case this.keyCode.SPACE:
      case this.keyCode.RETURN:
        if (this.isExpandable) {
          if (this.isExpanded()) {
            this.tree.collapseTreeitem(this);
          }
          else {
            this.tree.expandTreeitem(this);
          }
          flag = true;
        }
        else {
          event.stopPropagation();
          this.stopDefaultClick = true;
        }
        break;

      case this.keyCode.UP:
        this.tree.setFocusToPreviousItem(this);
        flag = true;
        break;

      case this.keyCode.DOWN:
        this.tree.setFocusToNextItem(this);
        flag = true;
        break;

      case this.keyCode.RIGHT:
        if (this.isExpandable) {
          if (this.isExpanded()) {
            this.tree.setFocusToNextItem(this);
          }
          else {
            this.tree.expandTreeitem(this);
          }
        }
        flag = true;
        break;

      case this.keyCode.LEFT:
        if (this.isExpandable && this.isExpanded()) {
          this.tree.collapseTreeitem(this);
          flag = true;
        }
        else {
          if (this.inGroup) {
            this.tree.setFocusToParentItem(this);
            flag = true;
          }
        }
        break;

      case this.keyCode.HOME:
        this.tree.setFocusToFirstItem();
        flag = true;
        break;

      case this.keyCode.END:
        this.tree.setFocusToLastItem();
        flag = true;
        break;

      default:
        if (isPrintableCharacter(char)) {
          printableCharacter(this);
        }
        break;
    }
  }

  if (flag) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    event.preventDefault();
  }
};

TreeitemLink.prototype.handleClick = function (event) {

  // only process click events that directly happened on this treeitem
  if (event.target !== this.domNode && event.target !== this.domNode.firstElementChild) {
    return;
  }

  if (this.isExpandable) {
    if (this.isExpanded()) {
      this.tree.collapseTreeitem(this);
    }
    else {
      this.tree.expandTreeitem(this);
    }
    event.stopPropagation();
  }
};

TreeitemLink.prototype.handleFocus = function (event) {
  var node = this.domNode;
  if (this.isExpandable) {
    node = node.firstElementChild;
  }
  node.classList.add('focus');
};

TreeitemLink.prototype.handleBlur = function (event) {
  var node = this.domNode;
  if (this.isExpandable) {
    node = node.firstElementChild;
  }
  node.classList.remove('focus');
};

TreeitemLink.prototype.handleMouseOver = function (event) {
  event.currentTarget.classList.add('hover');
};

TreeitemLink.prototype.handleMouseOut = function (event) {
  event.currentTarget.classList.remove('hover');
};

/*
*   This content is licensed according to the W3C Software License at
*   https://www.w3.org/Consortium/Legal/2015/copyright-software-and-document
*
*   File:   TreeLinks.js
*
*   Desc:   Tree widget that implements ARIA Authoring Practices
*           for a tree being used as a file viewer
*/

/**
 * ARIA Treeview example
 * @function onload
 * @desc  after page has loaded initialize all treeitems based on the role=treeitem
 */

window.addEventListener('load', function () {

  var trees = document.querySelectorAll('[role="tree"]');

  for (var i = 0; i < trees.length; i++) {
    var t = new TreeLinks(trees[i]);
    t.init();
  }

});

/*
*   @constructor
*
*   @desc
*       Tree item object for representing the state and user interactions for a
*       tree widget
*
*   @param node
*       An element with the role=tree attribute
*/

var TreeLinks = function (node) {
  // Check whether node is a DOM element
  if (typeof node !== 'object') {
    return;
  }

  this.domNode = node;

  this.treeitems = [];
  this.firstChars = [];

  this.firstTreeitem = null;
  this.lastTreeitem = null;

};

TreeLinks.prototype.init = function () {

  function findTreeitems (node, tree, group) {

    var elem = node.firstElementChild;
    var ti = group;

    while (elem) {

      if ((elem.tagName.toLowerCase() === 'li' && elem.firstElementChild.tagName.toLowerCase() === 'span') || elem.tagName.toLowerCase() === 'a') {
        ti = new TreeitemLink(elem, tree, group);
        ti.init();
        tree.treeitems.push(ti);
        tree.firstChars.push(ti.label.substring(0, 1).toLowerCase());
      }

      if (elem.firstElementChild) {
        findTreeitems(elem, tree, ti);
      }

      elem = elem.nextElementSibling;
    }
  }

  // initialize pop up menus
  if (!this.domNode.getAttribute('role')) {
    this.domNode.setAttribute('role', 'tree');
  }

  findTreeitems(this.domNode, this, false);

  this.updateVisibleTreeitems();

  this.firstTreeitem.domNode.tabIndex = 0;

};

TreeLinks.prototype.setFocusToItem = function (treeitem) {

  for (var i = 0; i < this.treeitems.length; i++) {
    var ti = this.treeitems[i];

    if (ti === treeitem) {
      ti.domNode.tabIndex = 0;
      ti.domNode.focus();
    }
    else {
      ti.domNode.tabIndex = -1;
    }
  }

};

TreeLinks.prototype.setFocusToNextItem = function (currentItem) {

  var nextItem = false;

  for (var i = (this.treeitems.length - 1); i >= 0; i--) {
    var ti = this.treeitems[i];
    if (ti === currentItem) {
      break;
    }
    if (ti.isVisible) {
      nextItem = ti;
    }
  }

  if (nextItem) {
    this.setFocusToItem(nextItem);
  }

};

TreeLinks.prototype.setFocusToPreviousItem = function (currentItem) {

  var prevItem = false;

  for (var i = 0; i < this.treeitems.length; i++) {
    var ti = this.treeitems[i];
    if (ti === currentItem) {
      break;
    }
    if (ti.isVisible) {
      prevItem = ti;
    }
  }

  if (prevItem) {
    this.setFocusToItem(prevItem);
  }
};

TreeLinks.prototype.setFocusToParentItem = function (currentItem) {

  if (currentItem.groupTreeitem) {
    this.setFocusToItem(currentItem.groupTreeitem);
  }
};

TreeLinks.prototype.setFocusToFirstItem = function () {
  this.setFocusToItem(this.firstTreeitem);
};

TreeLinks.prototype.setFocusToLastItem = function () {
  this.setFocusToItem(this.lastTreeitem);
};

TreeLinks.prototype.expandTreeitem = function (currentItem) {

  if (currentItem.isExpandable) {
    currentItem.domNode.setAttribute('aria-expanded', true);
    this.updateVisibleTreeitems();
  }

};

TreeLinks.prototype.expandAllSiblingItems = function (currentItem) {
  for (var i = 0; i < this.treeitems.length; i++) {
    var ti = this.treeitems[i];

    if ((ti.groupTreeitem === currentItem.groupTreeitem) && ti.isExpandable) {
      this.expandTreeitem(ti);
    }
  }

};

TreeLinks.prototype.collapseTreeitem = function (currentItem) {

  var groupTreeitem = false;

  if (currentItem.isExpanded()) {
    groupTreeitem = currentItem;
  }
  else {
    groupTreeitem = currentItem.groupTreeitem;
  }

  if (groupTreeitem) {
    groupTreeitem.domNode.setAttribute('aria-expanded', false);
    this.updateVisibleTreeitems();
    this.setFocusToItem(groupTreeitem);
  }

};

TreeLinks.prototype.updateVisibleTreeitems = function () {

  this.firstTreeitem = this.treeitems[0];

  for (var i = 0; i < this.treeitems.length; i++) {
    var ti = this.treeitems[i];

    var parent = ti.domNode.parentNode;

    ti.isVisible = true;

    while (parent && (parent !== this.domNode)) {

      if (parent.getAttribute('aria-expanded') == 'false') {
        ti.isVisible = false;
      }
      parent = parent.parentNode;
    }

    if (ti.isVisible) {
      this.lastTreeitem = ti;
    }
  }

};

TreeLinks.prototype.setFocusByFirstCharacter = function (currentItem, char) {
  var start, index, char = char.toLowerCase();

  // Get start index for search based on position of currentItem
  start = this.treeitems.indexOf(currentItem) + 1;
  if (start === this.treeitems.length) {
    start = 0;
  }

  // Check remaining slots in the menu
  index = this.getIndexFirstChars(start, char);

  // If not found in remaining slots, check from beginning
  if (index === -1) {
    index = this.getIndexFirstChars(0, char);
  }

  // If match was found...
  if (index > -1) {
    this.setFocusToItem(this.treeitems[index]);
  }
};

TreeLinks.prototype.getIndexFirstChars = function (startIndex, char) {
  for (var i = startIndex; i < this.firstChars.length; i++) {
    if (this.treeitems[i].isVisible) {
      if (char === this.firstChars[i]) {
        return i;
      }
    }
  }
  return -1;
};
```

```css
ul[role="tree"] {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

ul[role="tree"] li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

ul[role="tree"] a {
  text-decoration: underline;
  border-color: transparent;
}

[role="treeitem"] ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin-left: 0.9em;
}

[role="treeitem"][aria-expanded="false"] > ul {
  display: none;
}

[role="treeitem"][aria-expanded="true"] > ul {
  display: block;
}

[role="treeitem"][aria-expanded="false"] > span::before {
  content: url(https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-practices-1.1/examples/treeview/treeview-2/images/right-arrow-brown.png);
  position: relative;
  left: -0.25em;
}

[role="treeitem"][aria-expanded="true"] > span::before {
  content: url(https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-practices-1.1/examples/treeview/treeview-2/images/down-arrow-brown.png);
  position: relative;
  left: -0.25em;
}

[role="treeitem"],
[role="treeitem"] span {
  width: 16em;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0.125em;
  border: 2px transparent solid;
  display: block;
}

/* disable default keyboard focus styling for treeitems
   Keyboard focus is styled with the following CSS */
[role="treeitem"]:focus {
  outline: 0;
}

[role="treeitem"].focus,
[role="treeitem"] span.focus {
  border-color: black;
  background-color: #eee;
}

[role="treeitem"].hover,
[role="treeitem"] span.hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}
```

```html
<h3 id="tree1">
  Foods
</h3>
<ul role="tree" aria-labelledby="tree1">
  <li role="treeitem"
      aria-level="1"
      aria-setsize="3"
      aria-posinset="1"
      aria-expanded="false">
    <span>
      Fruits (expand me)
    </span>
    <ul>
    <li role="none">
        <a role="treeitem"
           aria-level="2"
           aria-setsize="6"
           aria-posinset="1"
           href="#AllFruitsURL">
          <strong>**All Fruits**</strong>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li role="none">
        <a role="treeitem"
           aria-level="2"
           aria-setsize="6"
           aria-posinset="2"
           href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orange_%28fruit%29">
          Oranges
        </a>
      </li>
      <li role="none">
        <a role="treeitem"
           aria-level="2"
           aria-setsize="6"
           aria-posinset="3"
           href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pineapple">
          Pineapple
        </a>
      </li>
      <li role="treeitem"
          aria-level="2"
          aria-setsize="6"
          aria-posinset="4"
          aria-expanded="false">
        <span>
          Apples
        </span>
        <ul role="group">
          <li role="none">
            <a role="treeitem"
               aria-level="3"
               aria-setsize="3"
               aria-posinset="1"
               href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/McIntosh_%28apple%29">
              Macintosh
            </a>
          </li>
          <li role="none">
            <a role="treeitem"
               aria-level="3"
               aria-setsize="3"
               aria-posinset="2"
               href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Granny_Smith">
              Granny Smith
            </a>
          </li>
          <li role="none">
            <a role="treeitem"
               aria-level="3"
               aria-setsize="3"
               aria-posinset="3"
               href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuji_(apple)">
              Fuji
            </a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li role="none">
        <a role="treeitem"
           aria-level="2"
           aria-setsize="6"
           aria-posinset="5"
           href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banana">
          Bananas
        </a>
      </li>
      <li role="treeitem"
          aria-level="2"
          aria-setsize="6"
          aria-posinset="6"
          aria-expanded="false">
        <span>
          Pears
        </span>
        <ul role="group">
          <li role="none">
            <a role="treeitem"
               aria-level="3"
               aria-setsize="6"
               aria-posinset="1"
               href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D%27Anjou">
              Anjou
            </a>
          </li>
          <li role="none">
            <a role="treeitem"
               aria-level="3"
               aria-setsize="6"
               aria-posinset="2"
               href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Williams_pear">
              Bartlett
            </a>
          </li>
          <li role="none">
            <a role="treeitem"
               aria-level="3"
               aria-setsize="6"
               aria-posinset="3"
               href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bosc_pear">
              Bosc
            </a>
          </li>
          <li role="none">
            <a role="treeitem"
               aria-level="3"
               aria-setsize="6"
               aria-posinset="4"
               href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pyrus_communis">
              Concorde
            </a>
          </li>
          <li role="none">
            <a role="treeitem"
               aria-level="3"
               aria-setsize="6"
               aria-posinset="5"
               href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pyrus_communis">
              Seckel
            </a>
          </li>
          <li role="none">
            <a role="treeitem"
               aria-level="3"
               aria-setsize="6"
               aria-posinset="6"
               href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pyrus_communis">
              Starkrimson
            </a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li role="treeitem"
      aria-level="1"
      aria-setsize="3"
      aria-posinset="2"
      aria-expanded="false">
    <span>
      Vegetables
    </span>
    <ul role="group">
      <li role="treeitem"
          aria-level="2"
          aria-setsize="3"
          aria-posinset="1"
          aria-expanded="false">
        <span>
          Podded Vegetables
        </span>
        <ul role="group">
          <li role="none">
            <a role="treeitem"
               aria-level="3"
               aria-setsize="3"
               aria-posinset="1"
               href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lentil">
              Lentil
            </a>
          </li>
          <li role="none">
            <a role="treeitem"
               aria-level="3"
               aria-setsize="3"
               aria-posinset="2"
               href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pea">
              Pea
            </a>
          </li>
          <li role="none">
            <a role="treeitem"
               aria-level="3"
               aria-setsize="3"
               aria-posinset="3"
               href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peanut">
              Peanut
            </a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li role="treeitem"
          aria-level="2"
          aria-setsize="3"
          aria-posinset="2"
          aria-expanded="false">
        <span>
          Bulb and Stem Vegetables
        </span>
        <ul role="group">
          <li role="none">
            <a role="treeitem"
               aria-level="3"
               aria-setsize="4"
               aria-posinset="1"
               href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asparagus">
              Asparagus
            </a>
          </li>
          <li role="none">
            <a role="treeitem"
               aria-level="3"
               aria-setsize="4"
               aria-posinset="2"
               href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Celery">
              Celery
            </a>
          </li>
          <li role="none">
            <a role="treeitem"
               aria-level="3"
               aria-setsize="4"
               aria-posinset="3"
               href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leek">
              Leek
            </a>
          </li>
          <li role="none">
            <a role="treeitem"
               aria-level="3"
               aria-setsize="4"
               aria-posinset="4"
               href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Onion">
              Onion
            </a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li role="treeitem"
          aria-level="2"
          aria-setsize="3"
          aria-posinset="3"
          aria-expanded="false">
        <span>
          Root and Tuberous Vegetables
        </span>
        <ul role="group">
          <li role="none">
            <a role="treeitem"
               aria-level="3"
               aria-setsize="4"
               aria-posinset="1"
               href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carrot">
              Carrot
            </a>
          </li>
          <li role="none">
            <a role="treeitem"
               aria-level="3"
               aria-setsize="4"
               aria-posinset="2"
               href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ginger">
              Ginger
            </a>
          </li>
          <li role="none">
            <a role="treeitem"
               aria-level="3"
               aria-setsize="4"
               aria-posinset="3"
               href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsnip">
              Parsnip
            </a>
          </li>
          <li role="none">
            <a role="treeitem"
               aria-level="3"
               aria-setsize="4"
               aria-posinset="4"
               href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Potato">
              Potato
            </a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you Graham for your suggestion. I will need to discussed your solution with my team. We are trying to build a fully wai compliant website, so every new decision we make needs to get approved. Thanks again!!!

Comment: Hi Graham, I have got another question related to WAI standard. Have you ever heard that only button can trigger an action like open up a modal dialog, but not a link? The wai auditor said to us that we need to have buttons inside the treeview in order to bring in a dialog. Basically each node can trigger a modal dialog to show its details. However, when I put <button> inside of <li role="treeitem">, Jaws will read "blank" when focus on the button. Then someone suggested to have <li role='none"><button role="treeitem"/></li>. Is <button role="treeitem"/> a valid thing?? Thanks so much

Comment: Do you want to put a basic fiddle together of what you mean and I will have a look for you? I think I follow but without seeing the actual setup I can't work out if there is another way to do what you want as giving a button a treeitem role is not something I have ever needed to do.

Comment: Please check it out. Basically, we move the parent company down as the first child node, use a button click to trigger a detail dialog to show. I am not sure about this bit <button role="treeitem"/>, it seems invalid to me. According to the wai auditing company, (sorry I cannot mention the company name, they are one of the well-known company globally)  we have to use button to trigger dialog.        https://codepen.io/hzhang99/pen/YzqBqWm

Comment: Hi Graham, I know this is a tough problem to solve. I couldn't find anything related to this type of user case anywhere online. That's the result came after some internal discussion. But it seems like this will pass the wai compliance. I just want to have a second opinion on this one. Thanks so much!!!

Comment: Sorry it took me a while to come back to you. It seems to work OK from what I can see. The only thing I am trying to get my head around is if you can use [`aria-haspopup`](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-1.1/#aria-haspopup) attribute to indicate it will open a modal / dialog. Not the end of the world if it doesn't as you can just follow best practices for a modal (focus the heading when it opens if there are no inputs (using `tabindex="-1"`), ensure it closes with ESC, ensure focus gets trapped, use `aria-modal="true"` etc.) but it would be good to include this info for screen readers if valid.

Comment: Thanks Graham, our modal dialog has already passed the wai auditing with all the necessary attributes and behaviors. The only thing failed is just the tree view structure. Yes, we need to have something on the button to inform users that it's clickable and trigger a popup. Aria-haspopup seemd like a good idea, thanks so much for your help!! You are a WAI legend!!